# How to find image, pre-image, bijection, onto, one-to-one?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

The question I am trying to solve is as follows:

Let A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} and define the function f : (A) → Z as follows:
For each set X in (A), where (A) is the power set of A, f(X) is the
number of elements in X.

a. What is the image of {1, 2, 3} under f? Justify.

b. What is the pre-image of 4? Justify.

c. What is the pre-image of 10? Justify.

d. Is f one-to-one? Justify.

e. Is f onto? Justify

My professor is not teaching us anything at all and my understanding of what onto, one-to-one, image, and pre-image is extremely weak because of this. Could someone please explain what these are in concrete, simple terms so that I may understand, and also push me in the right direction as far as solving a problem like this?

Thank you!

Comment: You should delete this post and ask questions about the definitions you found on Google. Then, when you understand the definitions, you can attempt the exercises.

Comment: don't delete nothing, you are free to ask whatever you want (about maths)

Comment: those concepts are easy: think on the identity card of you country. This is a function that gives a unique ID to every person. This is ONTO because every person is mapped to a unique id, it is not possible that two personas has the same id. (oher examples are $f(x)=2x, f(x) = -x $

Comment: A quick google search provides these two links, both seem to have good explanations. [This link](https://textbooks.math.gatech.edu/ila/one-to-one-onto.html) is a link to a textbook with helpful pictures. [This one](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/matrix-transformations/inverse-transformations/v/surjective-onto-and-injective-one-to-one-functions) is a Khan Academy tutorial page, maybe check these out, then see if you can answer your question. If you still don't understand a certain concept, try to find your own resource, maybe one which explains power sets could help.

Comment: image and preimage are easy-learn concepts too. We will use a quotient mapping: think on a function that takes as input a  professional person and takes him the room of persons of their job. So the image of the doctor Juan will be a room with all doctors form all the world, and the preimage of room "mechanic" will be a set of all personas who are mechanics.

Comment: @LuisFelipe If there is a question about concept, then it should be asked. This post starts with a problem set.

Comment: @LuisFelipe No but I have been a member a long time and wish to maintain the standards of this site. We are not.a homework solving site and I don't appreciate your rudeness.

Answer (score 2):

The function is defined on the power set of A, that is the set (or collection) of all subsets of A. The function $f$ just assigns to each subset of A the number of elements in the subset. The set {1,2,3} has 3 elements so f maps it to?
To see what the premiage of 4 is, all you need to know is how many subsets of A are mapped to 4 under f. This translates to how many subsets of A have 4 elements in them.
How many subsets of A have 10 elements?
Can two different subsets of A have the same number of elements.
For each integer $n$, is there a subset of A which has$n$ elements? Question 3 might be useful here.

Answer (score 1):

- Consider a function  f from A = { a, b} to B = { c, d, e, m} such that  f(a) = d  and f(b) = e.
- The image of a under f is d and the image of b under f is e.

This is equivalent to saying that the preimage of d is a and the preimage of e is b.

- The funbction is one-to-one, since no two different elements in A  have the same image in B.
- The function is not onto since there is at least one element of B that has no preimage in A under f.